# How to integrate AWS Secret Manager with Spring Boot Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

I have a requirement to retrieve credentials from AWS Secret Manager, and I found that I need to add the gradle dependency for the following starter

```
spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config
```

Also, i found that I need to add the following settings in Bootstrap.yml

[Property Configurations](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.1.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__cloud_environment.html)

I'm unclear how secret key could be accessed in my Spring Boot Application if someone could chime in much appreciated.

Comment: When do you need these credentials/what are these credentials for?  You could retrieve these credentials at runtime - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/java-secretsmanager-src-main-java-aws-example-secretsmanager-GetSecretValue.java.html

Comment: I figured out that there is no additional configuration required only thing need to be completed is setting up my secrets in AWS secret manager console.All the secrets are available with specific key I have specified.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would like to share my findings on SecretManager integration with Spring Boot application.

Step 1. Add `spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config` dependency in Spring Boot Application ( Gradle and Maven ways of adding dependency is different).

Step 2. Add the following configuration in bootstrap.yml file.

```
aws:
  secretsmanager:
    prefix: /secret
    defaultContext: application
    profileSeparator: _
    failFast: true
    name: <service_name>
    enabled: true
```

Step 3. create secrets in AWS Management console for the region required.

There are two secrets contexts

1. Application context - Shared secrets across all services.
2. Service context - secrets specific to service.

Final note on creating secrets,Secrets could be created for each environments.

For example,

```
/secret/service_name_dev/username

/secret/service_name_prod/username
```

Application context secrets could be created according to following format.

```
/secret/application/username
```

Once Spring Boot application started with above settings, Application will load secrets from AWS Secret Manager based on active profile.

For example,
for a dev profile, it will load the secret /secret/service_name_dev/username, and the value could be accessed in configuration as well as in classes using ${username} mapping.

Comment: what spring boot version where you using? it is not working for me. I'm migrating from a spring boot 1.5 to 2.1.6

Comment: that my issue :) the only error i get is "cant create bean of type X" where X is my class that needs the aws secrets as config

Comment: found my problem. not related to this. I was missing a @ComponentScan(...) on my MainApp Class

Comment: it is not working with Spring Boot 2 at all. I have the error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.<init>([Ljava/lang/Object;)V

Comment: @Alex probably you have dependency conflict.I had similar issue with spring-cloud-aws-context

Comment: @pubudut yes, the Greenwich.SR1 BOM needs to be used. Unfortunately, the Spring Cloud Documentation is very unclear about that.

Comment: true i had to go through bit of hassle to understand how to do documentation is not clear

Comment: Is there a way not to incldue the profile? My secret is just /secret/service_name/username but SpringBoot insists in looking for /secret/service_name_dev/username_development, hilariously, if I regenerate the secret so it is /secret/service_name/username_development then SpringBoot fails because it looks for /secret/service_name/username

Comment: Is there any solution to remove the slash, all my secrets doesn't have the prefix / or /secret, please let me know if you have any approach . I use the same library from spring cloud: spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config. 
Many thanks!

Comment: @mesmed Per this [page](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-aws/2.1.0.RELEASE/multi/multi__cloud_environment.html), you can configure the prefix using 
    aws.secretsmanager.prefix property

Answer (score 9):

If you are using springboot 2.4+ the bootstrap method has been deprecated. The new way of integrate aws secret manager is this:

1. Add the following dependency to your app:

   ```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.awspring.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
        <version>${version}</version>
    </dependency>
   ```
2. Add the following configuration:

   `spring.config.import: aws-secretsmanager:<your secret name in aws>`

That's it!

Comment: How to make this run only for aws cloud and not for local spring

Comment: @sromit You would need to exclude the autoconfigure classes in your local profile.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above maybe wrong.
The configuration store in secret manager should be:

`key: /secret/application
value: {"username":"test"}`

Answer (score 1):

For enabling aws secrets manager with spring boot application configuration is not required We are just required to add below dependencies

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config</artifactId>
<!--<version> As per your spring-cloud-dependencies And starter parent version 
</version>-->
</dependency>
```

If you are not having spring-cloud-context dependency add the same in your pom as well.

It enables the spring app to connect to your cloud and after that you can read secrets same way as you read them from properties file.
You can customize the properties configuration if you want, read the spring docs.
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/2.1.x/multi/multi__cloud_environment.html

After adding above changes to your code lets move to aws console and open secrets manger to add new secret for our application and follow below steps
Lets assume we are having a spring.application.name=secretmanagerboot
and parameter name as "com.secretmanagerboot.secret.param1" and its value is "secretvalue"

1. Click store on new secret
2. Select Other Types of secrets
3. Add parameter name as "com.secretmanagerboot.secret.param1" and parameter value as "secretvalue"
4. Click Next
5. Add secret name as secretmanagerboot<_PROFILE>
   You can add description if you want.
6. Click Next and select your rotation policy

You can access your param in application as 
@Value("${com.secretmanagerboot.secret.param1}")

Comment: Awesome! This helps

Comment: Is there any place we can look which dependency version of secrets manager is compatible with spring version

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Spring Boot V `2.6.2` then this our POM:

For Spring Boot:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.2</version>
</parent>
```

We have this to have all the related dependencies with the same version for `aws java sdk 2`:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.136</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

And then in our case we just use the `SecretManager` so we have:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>secretsmanager</artifactId>
    <version>2.17.121</version>
</dependency>
```

I had many difficulties in the dependencies because we needed `sdk 2` and not one. One general rule for aws dependency is that if you see `com.amazonaws` then it is `sdk v1`. Donot use them if you need `sdk v2`