# Trying to configure reading from secrets manager in spring boot and region error thrown

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

I am attempting to follow the answer here  [How to integrate AWS Secret Manager with Spring Boot Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194579/how-to-integrate-aws-secret-manager-with-spring-boot-application) also described https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-aws/2.1.x/multi/multi__cloud_environment.html .  It appears to be trying to read from secrets manager however when my service is starting up I am getting an error

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No region provided.`

I have tried setting the region as an environment variable and relaunching intelliJ but I still face this issue.  Any suggestions on how to set this region since I am not the one explicitly building the client?  I'm out of ideas.

To add:

My application.yml file has the following setup:

```
cloud:
  aws:
    region:
      static: us-east-1

secretsmanager:
  prefix: /secret
  defaultContext: application
  profileSeparator: _
  failFast: true
  name: platform
  enabled: true
```

I added the cloud section in an attempt to fix the error but it still does not boot

Answer (score 0):

I added the region as part of the environment variables in the tomcat startup and it resolved the issue