# AWS Secret Manager with Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, aws-secrets-manager

I tried to get secret manager value use this answer
[How to integrate AWS Secret Manager with Spring Boot Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194579/how-to-integrate-aws-secret-manager-with-spring-boot-application)
But my application get secrets 2 times, first as I want with local profile, but second without any profile. Why application go to secret second time and how can I off this?

```
2021-08-19 11:40:01.214  INFO 9141 --- [  restartedMain] s.AwsSecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator : Loading secrets from AWS Secret Manager secret with name: secret/test_local, optional: false
2021-08-19 11:40:02.702  INFO 9141 --- [  restartedMain] s.AwsSecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator : Loading secrets from AWS Secret Manager secret with name: secret/test, optional: false
2021-08-19 11:40:02.956 ERROR 9141 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
```

my config in bootstrap.yaml

```
aws:
  secretsmanager:
    prefix: secret
    defaultContext: application
    profileSeparator: _
    name: test
```

start application with `-Dspring.profiles.active=local`

upd. If I create secret for secret/test I have the next one

```
s.AwsSecretsManagerPropertySourceLocator : Loading secrets from AWS Secret Manager secret with name: secret/application_local, optional: false
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way to disable prefix/defaultContext look up.
If you take a look [here](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/blob/2b58c4513a1a76a83c5c13e91833dd936eae2e0f/spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager-config/src/main/java/io/awspring/cloud/secretsmanager/AwsSecretsManagerPropertySources.java#L50) you will see that prefix/ + defaultcontext of loading is always added and used.

You can check [docs](http://%20https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.3.1/reference/html/index.html#integrating-your-spring-cloud-application-with-the-aws-secrets-manager) as well, to have more clear way what is being loaded and in what order.

My recommendation is to switch to `spring.config.import` since that will be the way we are going to take Secrets Manager importing. Big difference is that, it gives users a lot more control of which secrets they want to import since you can specify each key individually. `spring.config.import` can be found explained in docs or you can check the project [sample](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/tree/2.3.x/spring-cloud-aws-samples/spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager-sample/src/main) .