# Importing secrets in Spring Boot application from AWS Secrets Manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config, aws-secrets-manager

I stored my MySQL DB credentials in AWS secrets manager using the `Credentials for other database` option. I want to import these credentials in my `application.properties` file. Based on a few answers I found in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56194579/how-to-integrate-aws-secret-manager-with-spring-boot-application), I did the following:

1. Added the dependency `spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config`
2. Added `spring.application.name = <application name>` and `spring.config.import = aws-secretsmanager: <Secret name>` in `application.properties`
3. Used secret keys as place holders in the following properties:

> ```
> spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://${host}:3306/db_name
> spring.datasource.username=${username}
> spring.datasource.password=${password}
> ```

I am getting the following error while running the application:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'aws-secretsmanager:<secret_name>'
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader. If the location is meant to reference a directory, it must end in '/' or File.separator
```

First, is the process I am following correct? If yes, what is this error regarding and how to resolve this?

Comment: Do you specify all your secrets withint `spring.config.import`? If not and if you want to resolve them by your application name, try using `spring.config.import=aws-secretsmanager:` (see the explanation [here](https://docs.awspring.io/spring-cloud-aws/docs/2.3.2/reference/html/index.html#spring-boot-configuration-import-support-2))

Comment: I have all the keys I want in one secret `/secret/<app_name>_<profile>/credentials`. I am using `spring.config.import=aws-secretsmanager:/secret/<app_name>_<profile>/credentials`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found the problem that was causing the error. Apparently I was adding the wrong dependency.

According to the latest docs, the configuration support for using `spring.config.import` to import AWS secrets has been moved to `io.awspring.cloud` from `org.springframework.cloud`. So the updated dependency would be `io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config:2.3.3` and **NOT** `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config:2.2.6`

Comment: could you please help with this particular issue with config import https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264774/retrieve-multiple-aws-secrete-in-spring-boot-app-that-have-same-keys

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to use `spring.config.import`, and the support for this was introduced in Spring Cloud 2.3.0:

https://spring.io/blog/2021/03/17/spring-cloud-aws-2-3-is-now-available

> Secrets Manager
>
> ```
> Support loading properties through spring.config.import, introduced in Spring Cloud 2020.0 Read more about integrating your
> ```
>
> Spring Cloud applicationwiththe AWS secrets manager.
> Removed the dependency to auto-configure module #526.
> Dropped the dependency to javax.validation:validation-api.
> Allow Secrets Manager prefix without “/” in the front #736.

---

---

> In spring-cloud 2020.0.0 (aka Ilford), the bootstrap phase is no
> longer enabled by default. In order enable it you need an additional
> dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap</artifactId>
  <version>{spring-cloud-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

> However, starting at spring-cloud-aws 2.3, allows import default aws'
> secretsmanager keys (spring.config.import=aws-secretsmanager:) or
> individual keys
> (spring.config.import=aws-secretsmanager:secret-key;other-secret-key)

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-aws/blob/main/docs/src/main/asciidoc/secrets-manager.adoc

---

---

**application.yml**

```
spring.config.import: aws-secretsmanager:/secrets/spring-cloud-aws-sample-app
```

Or try to leave it empty:

```
spring.config.import=aws-secretsmanager:
```

As such, it will take spring.application.name by default,

**App:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner applicationRunner(@Value("${password}") String password) {
        return args -> {
            LOGGER.info("`password` loaded from the AWS Secret Manager: {}", password);
        };
    }

}
```

Comment: As per the link, to import on the basis of application name and profile, we need to use just `spring.config.import=aws-secretsmanager:`. Still not working. Same error.

Comment: Did you check your aws cloud version?  Please see note

Comment: I have `'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config:2.2.6.RELEASE'` and `"org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:2020.0.4"`. Why exactly do we need the `'io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-aws:2.3.0'` dependency? I tried adding it. Did not help. Also we need the bootstrap dependency only when we are configuring through a `bootstrap.yml` file according to the article.