# Retrieve multiple aws secrete in spring boot app that have same keys

Tags: spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

Have a spring boot app (with starter parent at 2.4.8).

The app is connecting to multiple data sources, and the automated Jenkins job being used to create secrets across company does it such a way that although secrets names are different(per app/source) but they all have same value underneath - 'username' and 'password' text.

For example:

1. first secret would be '/secret/rds/dev/foo/foo_app_user' with value:

   ```
      username : user1 
      password: pass1
   ```
2. second secret would be '/secret/snowflake/dev/hoo/hoo_app_user' with value:

   ```
       username : user2
       password: pass2
   ```

Trying to figure out how can they both be imported using spring config import, while still being able to be used distinctively in properties/yaml file

```
  spring:
     config:
        import: aws secretsmanager:/secret/rds/dev/foo/foo_app_user,/secret/snowflake/dev/hoo/hoo_app_user


...
system:
  cache:
    username: ${username}
    password: ${password}



....
snowflake:
   datasource:
        username: ${username}
        password: ${password}
```

Answer (score 0):

3 days ago 13th Jan, 2023 this issue has been fixed. [Commit ref](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/commit/4d9da9a46185559e1b0a0308eae5eb0f31f140f1)

With spring cloud `3.0.x` (dependent on spring boot `3.0.x`) you can add prefix

```yaml
spring:
     config:
        import: 
          - aws-secretsmanager:/secret/rds/dev/foo/foo_app_user?prefix=foo_app.
          - aws-secretsmanager:/secret/snowflake/dev/hoo/hoo_app_user?prefix=hoo_app.
```

---

Now as a workaround for spring cloud version `2.4.x` we have

- copied the class `AwsSecretsManagerPropertySource` into our codebase in package `io.awspring.cloud.secretsmanager`. [Code Ref](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/blob/2.4.x/spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager-config/src/main/java/io/awspring/cloud/secretsmanager/AwsSecretsManagerPropertySource.java)
- Then use similler implementation approach as version `3.0.x`. [Code Ref](https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/blob/main/spring-cloud-aws-secrets-manager/src/main/java/io/awspring/cloud/secretsmanager/SecretsManagerPropertySource.java)

*PS: Don't change the class signature. Method name, constructor param should be same as version `2.4.x`*

---

**Edit: 5th Feb, 2023**

With new `2.4.3` version you can pass the same prefix. No need to do workaround.

Comment: i am trying to use above approach (adding prefix) in my spring boot app (Spring Boot version 2.7.8, JDK 11), by copying the class AwsSecretsManagerPropertySource and trying to customize  implementation, but getting mixed up. Appreciate if you can please give some more clarity, to help achieve solution quicker, to meet project needs ?

Comment: Use new version `2.4.3`, my fix got merged. No need for this workaround

Comment: apologies, still getting error, i am using below in pom  ->spring-cloud.version>2021.0.5,                                                   spring-cloud-aws-version>2.4.3 with spring boot 2.7.8. Upon reading secret spring.config. import as -> aws-secretsmanager:/secret/spring-boot-app?prefix=foo       getting error in app java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'aws-secretsmanager:/secret/spring-boot-app?prefix=foo' at <see second comment for full stack trace>

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'aws-secretsmanager:/secret/spring-boot-app?prefix=foo'
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferences(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:141)
 ..Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader. If the location is meant to reference a directory, it must end in '/' or File.separator
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.getReferencesForFile(StandardConfigDataLocationResolver.java:229)

Comment: without `?prefix=foo` is your application running? from the error it is not able to identify `aws-secretsmanager` property source class

Comment: with/without prefix, was only able to run with ->  spring cloud version - 2021.0.5 , spring cloud aws version - 3.0.0-M2, spring boot version 2.7.7, JDK 11. Other dependencies is io.awsspring.cloud / spring-cloud-aws-starter-secrets-manager

Comment: Just to be clear, only able to read secret in spring boot app with spring cloud aws version 3.0.0-M2 without preifx (see previous comment).

Comment: spring cloud aws that Im using is `2.2.6`. But this prefix thing has nothing to do with spring cloud aws. Also cloud version `3.0.0-M2` will have breaking change due to spring version compatibility, better to stick to `2.x.x` unless you are going spring boot `3.0.0`. you only need `io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config` version minimum `2.4.3` if your spring boot version is `2.x.x`

Comment: added a sample project, still unable to make it work. could you take a look please https://github.com/jobas2007/aws-secret-demo

Comment: Its working fine, you need to add few config as you are running on localstack. Created PR to fix: https://github.com/jobas2007/aws-secret-demo/pull/1/files

Once validated please merge