# Why can I not access my secrets when using AWS and Spring Boot?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

I have the following configuration

```
spring:
  config:
    import:
      - aws-secretsmanager:dev/CBusHA/Backend/
  datasource:
    url: ${spring.datasource.url}
    username: ${spring.datasource.username}
    password: ${spring.datasource.password}
```

But when I run I get

```
Config data location 'aws-secretsmanager:dev/CBusHA/Backend/' does not exist
```

But I have the following

[image]

I also tried

```
spring:
  config:
    import:
      - aws-secretsmanager:dev/CBusHA/Backend
  datasource:
    url: ${spring.datasource.url}
    username: ${spring.datasource.username}
    password: ${spring.datasource.password}
```

but I get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader. If the location is meant to reference a directory, it must end in '/' or File.separator
```

**Also**

using

`implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap:4.0.3'`

Answer (score 1):

As someone described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70461315/496289):

> According to the latest docs, the configuration support for using `spring.config.import` to import AWS secrets has been moved to `io.awspring.cloud` from `org.springframework.cloud`. So the updated dependency would be `io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config:2.3.3` and NOT `org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config:2.2.6`

Could you try adding appropriate version of `io.awspring.cloud:...aws-secrets-manager-config` to dependencies (and remove `org.springframework.cloud:...`)

Answer (score 0):

possibly the actual secret name in AWS Secrets Manager does not end with a '/'

maybe it works if you try to recreate the secret with name 'dev/CBusHA/Backend/', e.g.

`aws secretsmanager create-secret --name dev/CBusHA/Backend/ --secret-string "..."`

Answer (score 0):

The configuration support for using `spring.config.import` to import `AWS secrets`

Now:- `io.awspring.cloud`

Earlier:- `org.springframework.cloud`

So the `dependency` should be `io.awspring.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config:2.3.3`

Kindly add the dependencies in `pom.xml` or `build.gradle`

Answer (score -1):

The first error shows that the location does no exists, make sure that you have the necessary permissions to access the file location.

And the second error `IllegalStateException` shows that Spring couldn't recognize the file extension of the configuration.

Make sure that your AWS Secrets Manager configuration doesn't have any file extensions, as Spring Cloud AWS Secrets Manager expects the location to be a directory or a direct reference to a secret.

You don't necessarily need `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` if you are suing spring boot 2.4 or later, it's deprecated.

Spring Boot should automatically loads properties from AWS Secrets Manager if the necessary dependencies are present on the classpath, which is why you might not need to explicitly include `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap`

Ensure that you have added correct dependancies in `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` for Spring Cloud AWS Secrets Manager. and also try removing the `spring-cloud-starter-bootstrap` dependency if you're using a recent version of Spring Boot. Also, verify the path and permissions in AWS Secrets Manager.